# How to delete selected row in DataGrid using delete key with fixed column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

Is there a way I can delete a selected row in `DataGrid` using delete key with fixed column?

I have used code with command.manager event but it didn't delete the row if i use key down event it executes but it didn't delete the row in data grid. Here is the code I have used:

```
<Window x:Class="datagridcheck.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1336" Width="937">
    <Grid  Name="grid1" Margin="10,10,135,10">
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgUsers" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" CommandManager.PreviewExecuted="DriversDataGrid_PreviewDeleteCommandHandler"  Margin="174,0,346,0" GridLinesVisibility="None" MinColumnWidth="50" FontFamily="Times New Roman" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFF70000" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FF0017FF" RowBackground="#FFF5F2D4" FontSize="18" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Animated" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264" Height="483" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" SelectedIndex="0" PreviewKeyDown="dgUsers_PreviewKeyDown"   >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="FoodName" Width="90" Binding="{Binding FoodName}" MinWidth="90" Foreground="#FFFB1005" FontFamily="Times New Roman"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Width="90" Binding="{Binding Birthday}" MinWidth="90" Foreground="Red" FontFamily="Times New Roman" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Price" MinWidth="90" Width="90"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="443,378,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <WrapPanel Height="355" Margin="443,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="wrap1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="331">
            <WrapPanel Height="100" Width="100"/>
        </WrapPanel>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="443,428,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="FoodName" Binding="{Binding FoodName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Birthday" />
                </GridView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
namespace datagridcheck
          {
           public partial class MainWindow : Window
              {
                  public MainWindow()
                  {
                      InitializeComponent();
                  }
                  int i = 0;
                  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                  { 
                      Button bt = new Button();
                      bt.Name = "test";
                      bt.Content="eachtime"+ i.ToString();
                      bt.Width = 50;
                      bt.Height = 50;
                      i++;
                      wrap1.Children.Add(bt);
                      bt.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.bt_Click); 
                   }
                  void bt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
                      Button buts = sender as Button;
                      dgUsers.Items.Add(new User() { Id = 1, FoodName = Convert.ToString(buts.Content), Birthday = Convert.ToString(buts.Name) });
                  }
                  private void DriversDataGrid_PreviewDeleteCommandHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
                          {
                              if (e.Command == DataGrid.DeleteCommand)
                              {
                                  if (!(MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete?", "Please confirm.", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes))
                                  {
                                    e.Handled = true;
                                  }
                              }
                          }
               }
              public class User
              {
              public int Id { get; set; }
                      public string FoodName { get; set; }
                      public string Birthday { get; set; }
             }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly MVVM = Model(Data) + View(Screens) + ViewModel(Code+logic)

First XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="gd"  CanUserDeleteRows="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding DataVMs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemInVM, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">

            <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Gesture="Delete" Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand, Mode=OneWay}"  CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=gd, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </DataGrid.InputBindings>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="One" Binding="{Binding Un}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Two" Binding="{Binding Deux}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In code Behind of MainWindow add this, assuming DataViewModel wrapps your model:

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Initialize DataContext with some Data
            var dataContext = new DataViewCollectionModel
            {
                DataVMs = new ObservableCollection<DataViewModel>()

            };
            dataContext.DataVMs.Add(new DataViewModel { Un = 1, Deux = 2 });
            dataContext.DataVMs.Add(new DataViewModel { Un = 10, Deux = 20 });
            dataContext.DataVMs.Add(new DataViewModel { Un = 100, Deux = 200 });

            //Assign
            DataContext = dataContext;
        }
```

Now create You ViewModels :

1) BindableObject handles the notifications, it's the base class of all Viewmodels:

```
 public class BindableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

    }
```

DataViewCollectionModel is what you pass to the DataContext of your View (In this case MainWindow). it must notify changes. that's why it inherits BindableObject. and it has a list of DataViewModel.

```
class DataViewCollectionModel : BindableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<DataViewModel> dataVMs;
    private DataViewModel selectedItemInVM;
    public ObservableCollection<DataViewModel> DataVMs
    {
        get { return dataVMs; }
        set
        {
            if (dataVMs != value)
            {
                dataVMs = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DataVMs");
            }
        }
    }

    public DataViewModel SelectedItemInVM
    {
        get { return selectedItemInVM; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedItemInVM != value)
            {
                selectedItemInVM = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItemInVM");
            }
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand<DataViewModel> deleteCommand;
    public RelayCommand<DataViewModel> DeleteCommand
    {
        get { return deleteCommand ?? (deleteCommand = new RelayCommand<DataViewModel>(d => Delete(d))); }
    }

    private void Delete(DataViewModel d)
    {
        DataVMs.Remove(selectedItemInVM);
    }

}
```

and finaly, your DataViewModel  wich represents each row in the DataGrid.

```
 public class DataViewModel : BindableObject
    {

        public int Un { get; set; }
        public int Deux { get; set; }

    }
```

And as I am very friendly, I give you a helper that handles commands :

```
   public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
    {

        readonly Action<T> _execute = null;
        readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute = null;


        public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute((T)parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute((T)parameter);
        }

    }
```

To test just click Delete key when you select a Row.

Hope it helps.

Comment: how to use mvvm in my  code. i am new to wpf. i'm directly add item to datagrid but when i use itemssource to bind datagrid it delete the row in datagrid

Comment: thanks but when i click a button i want to populate one row when i click another button i want to populate on second row.but in this i'm able to populate only one row but i'm able to delete it

Comment: like delete add command add. I can update my answer but upvote me please !

Comment: Sir Please Update How to use command add..i don't have reputation to vote u but my friend vote u

Comment: just question of time. give some time